# Django base.html block overwriting

Tags: python, django, django-templates, wagtail, templatetags

I want to define, and append to blocks defined in the base.html template.

Say I have the following template

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Project</title>
        {% block append_to_me %}{% endblock %}
    </head>

    <body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
    </body>
</html>
```

I would then use the following template for my views,
my views render some wagtail components, and those components might
want to use the append_to_me block.

This goes not only for the *wagtail blocks*, but also for **plain django template tags**

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Content for My App</h2>
    <p>Stuff etc etc.</p>
    {# I want it to not matter where I use this. #}
    {% my_custom_tag %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Where `{% my_custom_tag %}` would do something like this:

```py
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def my_custom_tag(context):
    objects = Preload.objects.all()
    for object in objects:
        append_to_header_block(object.html)
```

Wagtail block example:

```py
class MyBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    title = blocks.CharBlock()
    content = blocks.RichTextBlock()

    class Meta:
        template = 'myapp/myblock.html'
```

myapp/myblock.html

```html
{% add_to_header IMG "img/my-img.jpeg" %}
...
```

I also want to be able to keep the content of previous calls to the `add_to_header` function,
as to not overwrite the previous content.

I just cannot figure out how I would implement this, because there are a few issues:

- Order of evaluation, I am pretty sure the content of base.html gets rendered before any of the other templates.

  - Maybe this can be fixed by *somehow* overwriting the `append_to_me` block from anywhere; and calling `block.super` every time? *Somehow* would be my question.
- Wagtail blocks might not even know they are not used in base.html due to their versatility.

Any ideas as to how I would implement this?
I am not even sure if this is possible, but I would love to hear your thoughts on this.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want done. Do you want the tag to add content to the `append_to_me` block only? If so, then why not just `{% block append_to_me %}{{ block.super }}{% my_custom_tag %}{% endblock %}`? You could also look into [InclusionTags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) and have the tags template overwrite the block.

Comment: Yes, I do want to append to it. I feel I was pretty clear in my question? If I could overwrite it; I would, but in this context it is not possible. I cannot overwrite the block from inside my own template tag, and neither can I overwrite it from wagtail blocks themselves, as I cannot do `extends base.html` from my template tags; for obvious reasons. This does not fit my needs. @CoffeeBasedLifeform

Comment: But in your template you're already overwriting the content block. What's stopping you from also overwriting the `append_to_me` block and calling the tag in there? That's what is not clear to me. If you can't change any of the templates at all, such that the tag is called in the right block, then you're out of luck, because tags are not aware of what block they are in; they just output HTML.

Comment: The template is an example to help visualise a setup. I cannot overwrite from inside the components. The tag might be multiple templates deep inside components.